# How to set cookies in getServerSideProps NextJS using universal-cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, next.js

I want to set a cookie from getGetServerSideProps using `universal-cookie`.

```
 import { NextPageContext } from 'next';
 import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

 export const getGetServerSideProps =
 () =>
  async ({ req, query }: NextPageContext) => {
  const cookies = new Cookies(req?.headers?.cookie);
  cookies.set('test-cookie', 'true', {
    httpOnly: true,
  });

 return {
   props: {
     isRegisterd:
       !!cookies.get('veriation'),
   },
 };
};
```

this doesn't seem working.

`cookies.get('veriation')`,  this is working, so `get` works fine, but not `set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a small typo in your code. The method you're using to set cookies is `set('test-cookie', 'true', { httpOnly: true }),` but then you're trying to retrieve a cookie named 'veriation' using `cookies.get('veriation')`. Make sure you're using the correct cookie name when setting and retrieving cookies.

Here's the corrected code:

```
import { NextPageContext } from 'next';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, query, res }: NextPageContext) => {
  const cookies = new Cookies(req?.headers?.cookie);
  cookies.set('test-cookie', 'true', {
    httpOnly: true,
  });

  // Set the cookie in the response's headers
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookies.getAll());

  return {
    props: {
      isRegistered: !!cookies.get('test-cookie'),
    },
  };
};
```

I've corrected the code to set the cookie with the name 'test-cookie' and then retrieve the same cookie to check if the user is registered. Make sure you're using the appropriate cookie name that matches your use case.

Comment: variation is another cookie, so what i mean is get is working,but not set

Comment: Check now i have updated the code

Comment: res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookies.getAll()); so res.setHeader is required to achive the intended result?

Comment: Yes, when you're using server-side rendering and you want to set cookies, you need to use res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ...) to include the cookies in the response headers. This is how you instruct the browser to set the cookies on the client side.

Comment: When you set a cookie using cookies.set(), the cookie is stored on the server side, but for the client's browser to actually receive and store the cookie, you need to send it in the response headers. This is achieved by using res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ...).

Comment: If you omit the res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ...) part, the cookie you set using cookies.set() might not be sent to the client's browser, and therefore the intended result might not be achieved.

So, to achieve the intended result of setting cookies and having them properly sent to the client's browser, you do need to use res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ...) in your server-side rendering code.

Comment: so I rather use res.setHeader('set-cookie', ['test_cookie=1']); without making use of universal-cookie right ?. this makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you only need to set cookies in your server-side rendering code and you don't need the additional features provided by the universal-cookie library, you can directly use res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ...) to set cookies in the response headers.

Comment: This is script
import { NextPageContext } from 'next';

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, query, res }: NextPageContext) => {
  // Set the cookie in the response's headers
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'test_cookie=1; HttpOnly');

  return {
    props: {
      // Your props here
    },
  };
};